# 2nd order ode with an even and an odd coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

may someone verify my solution? Consider two continuous functions $a,b: I=[-m,m]\neq \emptyset \to \mathbb{R}$, with $a$ odd and $b$ even. Show that

$$y''+ay'+by = 0$$

has a fundamental system consisting of an odd and an even function.
Idea:
Pick any solution $y \neq 0$, and construct odd or even solutions:
$$y_e(t) = y(t) + y(-t)$$
$$y_o(t) = y(t) - y(-t).$$
Then $y_e \neq 0$ is even and $y_o$ or $y$ is odd and not equal to $0$. Moreover, $y_e$ and $y_o$ (or y) are fullfilling the ode, f.e.

$$y_e''(t)+a(t)y_e'(t)+b(t)y_e(t) = y_e''(-t)-a(t)y_e'(-t) + b(t)y_e(-t)=y_e''(-t)+a(-t)y_e'(-t) + b(-t)y_e(-t) = 0$$

and are linearly independent.
Is this okay?

Edit: I have another problem here: If my solution $y$ is even, then $y_o=0$. Can I guarantee, that not all the solutions are even, or odd respectively?

Comment: The only thing I don't see here is the assertion that the system has a solution in the first place, which can be gotten from the standard existence/uniqueness theorem for second-order ODEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solve the initial value problems with $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=0$ and second $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$ and show with your already presented methodology that the first basis solution is even while the second is odd.

With your approach you can not be certain that the original solution is neither even nor odd, thus turn it around and make certain to select these symmetric solutions.

Comment: Ah, because an odd function has to map $0$ to $0$ and the derivative of an odd function is even and vice versa? Thus I know that the solution of the first iv problem cannot be odd, and the one of the second not even?

Comment: You just need to show that $y(-x)$ satisfies the same ODE with the same resp. negated initial conditions. Uniqueness of the solution does the rest.

Comment: Danke! But what I wrote should be true as well?